# Pros and Cons of saving image in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Now I am on a dilemma about whether to create a separate folder for byte[] images instead of using SQLite or do I save the images Blob in the SQLite?.

What would be the pros and cons of saving byte[] images in the SQLite?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the best practice is to save a URI as Text in SQLite, and keep all images in internal/external storage. Lots of Blobs can start degrading performance.

Comment: By degrading performance what do you mean? Slow down the application speed or the phone?

Comment: Would that be queries of retrieving the byte[] images? or overall queries aside from the images?

Comment: I think all queries, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, only one way to find out now. I am going to try it out. Thanks.